# Why does this sequence exist?

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

We have the following theorem from Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis Book 3 that says if $H$ is a Hilbert space, $f \in H$, and $S$ is a closed subspace of $H$, then there is an element $g_0 \in S$ such that $\|f-g_0\| = \inf_{g \in S}\|f-g\|$.

The proof starts out by letting $d = \inf_{g \in S}\|f-g\|$ and considering a sequence $\{g_n\} \subset S$ with the property that

$$\|f-g_n\| \rightarrow d \text{ as }n \to \infty $$

**I'm having trouble seeing why such a sequence $\{g_n\}$ should exist**. My intuition is telling me that I need to use the epsilon characterization of infimum. That is, if $A$ is a set of real numbers and $d := \inf A$, then

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists x \in A \text{ such that }x < d + \epsilon$$

Comment: Where exactly ist your problem? Because you are quasi answering your question...

Comment: How to use the epsilon characterization of infimum to explicitly construct the sequence $\{g_n\}$.

Comment: If $d$ is the infimum, it must be possible to approach it along some sequence (a minimizing sequence).

Comment: The proof here is simply one,of "pick, pick, pick...".  Choose (say) $g_n$ where $\epsilon = 1/n$.  Does this approach make sense to you?  Do you have doubts as to its validity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there must be an element $g_n\in S$ such that $d\leq ||f-g_n||<d+\frac{1}{n}$, this indeed follows from the epsilon characterization of infimum. By the squeeze theorem $||f-g_n||\to d$.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $g\in S$ with $||f-g|| < d + \epsilon$.  For suppose not; then for all $g \in S$, $||f-g|| \geq d + \epsilon$, which means that $d + \epsilon$ is a lower bound for $\{||f-g|| \big| g \in S\}$.  But $d + \epsilon > d$, a contradiction since $d$ is the *greatest* lower bound.

Now for any $n$, set $\epsilon = 1/n$ and use the above fact to find $g_n$ with $||f-g_n|| < d + 1/n$.  Since $d \leq ||f - g_n||$ by definition, we have $||f-g_n||\rightarrow d$.

Comment: Thanks Jair. In this post, are you implicitly proving the epsilon characterization of infimum in the special case of the set $\{||f-g|| \big| g \in S\}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (assuming the 'epsilon characterization of infimum' is what I think it is.)

Comment: I have it written out at the bottom of the question

Comment: Oh, I see now the you were already familiar with this so I could have skipped that step.

Comment: Yes, no problem. In either case, I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer. Thanks again.